# Javascript - replace elements with same class with different values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax

Quick one: Is it possible to replace the values of elements with the **SAME** class with different values?

Here's what I mean: I have this array returned by an AJAX response:

```js
[
  "$63.00 / Night",
  "$68.00 / Night",
  "$58.00 / Night",
  "$50.00 / Night"
]
```

The above array is generated from a html response that looks like this:

```js
    var result = [
      "$63.00 / Night",
      "$68.00 / Night",
      "$58.00 / Night",
      "$50.00 / Night"
    ];
    
    console.log(result[0]);
            
    result.forEach(function(item)
    {
     var num_price = parseFloat(item.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
     num_price = num_price * 2;
     console.log(num_price);
                          
     $('.gdlr-tail').html(num_price);
    });
```

```html
<span class="gdlr-tail">$63.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$65.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$67.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$72.00 / Night</span>
```

From the above, trouble kicks in on the last line of the code: `$('.gdlr-tail').html(num_price);` where it renders all the values in my `.gdlr-tail` class to be the value of the first span i.e all the values in the class are set to `126(63*2)`. This happens though my array is inside a loop. Only the first element is calculated with all the other elements being set to the value of this calculation.

Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: You have to iterate through `$('.gdlr-tail')` too. That's why only the first element is updated. I suggest you use a `for` and use the index to address the elements on both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the `.gdlr-tail` elements, and not the prices. Then assign to each element the corresponding value from the array:

```js
var result = [
  "$63.00 / Night",
  "$68.00 / Night",
  "$58.00 / Night",
  "$50.00 / Night"
];

$('.gdlr-tail').each(function(index, el)
{
    var num_price = parseFloat(result[index].replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
    num_price = num_price * 2;

    $(el).html(num_price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$63.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$65.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$67.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$72.00 / Night</span>
```

Comment: Elegant and concise, should be marked as the answer in my opinion

Comment: beautiful. twice you've saved my bacon. thanks. should note the other answers are also correct

Answer (score 1):

It is, but for sanity it's always best to group them first to avoid unwanted changes elsewhere on the page:

```js
var result = [
  "$63.00 / Night",
  "$68.00 / Night",
  "$58.00 / Night",
  "$50.00 / Night"
];

result.forEach(function(item, index) {

  var num_price = parseFloat(item.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
  num_price = num_price * 2;
  console.log(num_price);

  $('.gdlr-tail-parent .gdlr-tail:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').html(num_price);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gdlr-tail-parent">
  <span class="gdlr-tail">$63.00 / Night</span>
  <span class="gdlr-tail">$65.00 / Night</span>
  <span class="gdlr-tail">$67.00 / Night</span>
  <span class="gdlr-tail">$72.00 / Night</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your after something like this->

With the reformatting too. ?

```js
var result = [
  "$63.00 / Night",
  "$68.00 / Night",
  "$58.00 / Night",
  "$50.00 / Night"
];

var tails = $('.gdlr-tail');
result.forEach(function(item, index)
{
  var num_price = parseFloat(item.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
  num_price = num_price * 2;  
  $(tails[index]).text("$" + num_price.toFixed(2) + " / Night");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$63.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$65.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$67.00 / Night</span>
<span class="gdlr-tail">$72.00 / Night</span>
```